# Android emulator doesn't work with localhost api

Tags: android, api, localhost

So connecting my android emulator with an normal online api works but not with my localhost api (which also returns a json file).

The weird thing is that opening localhost (http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/person) in the emulators webbrowser which does return a webpage with json. But when in the code below it goes.

In the code below it always executes onErrorResponse(), Anyone any idea what i might have looked over?

Thanks.

I tried disabling my firewall and other ip adresses but to no avail.

```
MY MANIFEST
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXERCISE.JAVA
        NetworkManager.getInstance(this).getRequest("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/person", new VolleyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSucces(String result) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Civilization c = gson.fromJson(result, Civilization.class);



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


NETWORK MANAGAR.JAVA
public void getRequest(String prefixUrl, final VolleyCallBack volleyCallBack){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, prefixUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                volleyCallBack.onSucces(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("wrong", "Something went wrong");
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Try http://10.0.2.15

Comment: Try inside onErrorResponse printing the error : Log.e("Volly Error", error.toString());
TimeoutError no data is received from the server

Comment: Thanks monster Brain that was exactly it